# Segmentation fault in a custom Heap

Tags: c++, c++11, heap, priority-queue

It is not even performing push operation. It not calling push function just constructor call and segmentation fault. Why is this happening?

```
class Heap {
    vector<int> v;

     void Heapify(int x) {
        int mi = x;
        int l = 2 * x;
        int r = 2 * x + 1;

        if (v[mi] > v[l] && l < v.size()) {
            mi = l;


        }
        if (v[mi] > v[r] && r < v.size()) {
            mi = r;
        }

        if (mi != x) {
            swap(v[mi], v[x]);
            Heapify(mi);
        }
                       }
public:
    Heap() {

        v[0] = -1;
    }
    void push(int x) {

        v.push_back(x);
        int i = v.size()-1;
        int p = i / 2;
        while (i > 1 && v[i] < v[p]) {


            swap(v[p], v[i]);
            i = p;
            p = p / 2;

        }

    }
    void pop() {
        swap(v[v.size() - 1], v[1]);
        v.pop_back();
         Heapify(1);
    }


};
int main(){

    Heap h;
    h.push(5);

}
```

Comment: You get it because you have *undefined behavior*. You get the undefined behavior because you access the vector out of bounds. You access the vector out of bounds because it's empty (the size is zero).

Comment: The size of vector will be never zero because when object is created constructor will automatically push -1 into vector .

Comment: ***The size of vector will be never zero because when object is created constructor will automatically push -1 into vector*** That is wrong. `v[0] = -1;` tries to access a non existing position in an empty vector. It will not increase the size of the vector like push_back();

Comment: @Visluck *The size of vector will be never zero* -- You want proof that this statement is false?  `Heap() {  std::cout << "The size of the vector is " << v.size() << std::endl;  v[0] = -1; }` -- What do you see printed on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
Heap() {
        v[0] = -1; // Segfault.
}
```

At that point, the vector `v` is empty, and you try to assign the first element (`v[0]`). This is outside the bounds of the vector, so the behaviour of the program is undefined (here, a crash).

You should use `v.push_back(-1)` if you really want to insert `-1` at the start of the vector.